# Where is the end user documentation for Unity?

Tags: unity, documentation

Is there any end user documentation for the Unity launcher?

Failing that, is there at least something as tips&tricks or reference materials (for example, a list of available keyboard shortcuts, etc.)?

Failing that, is there any specification and/or developer documentation from which one could derive some useful information?

I'd especially like to have some reference about the way search works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Click on the Ubuntu button and look for help by typing "Help" in the dash and click on the Help icon:

[image]

This will pull up the documentation:

[image]

You can find the web version of the documentation here:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/11.10/ubuntu-help/index.html

We're also collecting tips and tricks here:

- [Tips and Tricks for Unity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36274/tips-and-tricks-for-unity)

Answer (score 4):

Nowhere. There are currently a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ayatana-design/+bug/600875) open about it, it doesn't get a lot of updates, but looks like at least some people are working on it.

Answer (score 4):

There's [OMG! Ubuntu!'s guide to Unity](http://omgubuntu.co.uk/natty/). You can also use the installed manual by selecting the help menu link from the [Application Menus](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10228/whats-the-right-terminology-for-unitys-ui-elements) (when the desktop is shown).

Answer (score 3):

There is a useful introduction on the [Canonical Design website](http://design.canonical.com/2010/06/introduction-to-unity-launcher/), including a video that shows how to use the launcher and its keyboard shortcuts.

I also saw a tip on the file manager that said that you can click on the folder icon in the top right-hand corner of the screen to open the current folder.

Comment: Thanks. This is not very much, but at least it shows that you can remove an icon from the launcher by drag&drop, something even the review on Ars Technica misses... I hope some information materializes about the application and files&folders searches.