# How can I put a shortcut to a file in the Unity launcher?

Tags: unity, 11.04, shortcuts

Is it possible to put a shortcut to a file (like a application launcher but opens a file instead of launching a program) in the Unity launcher, and if so, how?

Comment: Do you mean the launcher on the left, or the top panel? Also, which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: the launcher on the left. i use ubuntu 11.04.

Comment: For UI element terminology help, see [What's the right terminology for Unity's UI elements?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/10228/whats-the-right-terminology-for-unitys-ui-elements)

Answer (score 6):

I only know a dirty way:

1. Create a file `~/.local/share/applications/myfile.desktop`
2. Add the following to that file:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Name=MyFile
   Exec=gedit /path/to/a/text/file
   Icon=text
   Terminal=false
   Type=Application
   StartupNotify=true
   ```
3. Save it and make that file executable:

   ```
   chmod +x ~/.local/share/applications/myfile.desktop
   ```
4. Now browse to that file in Nautilus and drag it to the launcher.

This will add a launcher with a text icon, that opens `/path/to/a/text/file` with gedit:

[image]

Of course you need to change application/file/icon to whatever you want.

Comment: why didn't they make it easer to create links to files? in gnome-panel, every user was able to add, remove, edit things easily and according to his/her wishes. unity looks great, but i miss the individuality, the possibility to personalize, change.