# What is the term for the unity-menu/panel/input/taskbar/sidebar?

Tags: unity, menu, bug-reporting, terminology

I.e., under Unity, what is the term for the panel that is opened when I press the <kbd>super</kbd> or <kbd>window</kbd> key that allows me to search for what I want to open or do?

I've been tripping over myself with some bug reports, so I'd like to get my terminology straight before I make any more of a fool of myself!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the right terminology for Unity's UI elements?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/10228/whats-the-right-terminology-for-unitys-ui-elements)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called the Dash. See here:

- [What's the right terminology for Unity's UI elements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10228/whats-the-right-terminology-for-unitys-ui-elements)

Comment: Mark duplicate?