# Can I rearrange Unity lenses on the launcher?

Tags: 11.04, launcher, unity-2d, lenses

Is it possible to reorder Unity 2D lenses? I have several installed, and I want them in a different order on the launcher.

Comment: Do you mean [Launcher items](http://askubuntu.com/questions/10228/whats-the-right-terminology-for-unitys-ui-elements/19166#19166) or items in the Dash? Please clarify

Answer (score 1):

It's currently not possible to rearrange lenses in 11.04.