# Where can I locate the Gnome Classic Panel "Quick Launcher" icons in Unity

Tags: 11.04, unity, gnome-panel

I spend some time between both worlds, Unity and Gnome Classic (No Effects) and I would like to know where can I find the quick launch icons of the Gnome Classic panel in Unity so i can simply drag&drop them in the Unity Launcher.

Comment: With "Unity Panel" do you mean the launcher or the Dash (see [unity terminology](http://askubuntu.com/questions/10228/whats-the-right-terminology-for-unitys-ui-elements/19166#19166))? Please edit your answer.

Comment: Done con-f-use. Good point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, we import in your unity launcher icons existing launchers from gnome-panel, netbook-launcher, unity maverick, your desktop content and some docks like cairo-dock, docky, awn the first time you launch it. It tries to agregate duplicates to have just one icon in the launcher per application (but take into account custom applications path)

You can force that to happen again by:

1. resetting your launcher icon in unity to default: `gsettings reset com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites` (this is not mandatory, but at least, you start from a well-known base)
2. reset the migration tag to the first : `gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorite-migration "'3.0'"`
3. logout and login in the unity session, unity should trigger the migration tool at start
4. if you are interested in logs, you will find them at

   ```
   ~/.cache/unity/migration_script.log
   ```

(~/.cache corresponding to $XDG_CACHE_HOME if you redefined it)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's anywhere that the launchers themselves are stored, although there appears to be a list of them in gconf-editor > apps > panel and then somewhere in there, I can only see the default things as I don't use Gnome classic. However, it's probably best just to remember what you have, or look at it in there and then add them manually to the launcher. Just search for the application in the dash and then drag and drop it onto the launcher.