# One click to fold and double click to unfold menu

Tags: 11.04, indicator

I have ubuntu 11.04 installed. I like unity 3d. I am not sure it was always like this or after I installed the main menu indicator. When I click on an indicator with one click it folds. To unfold the menu I need to click twice. On all menus I can open the action by one click, but the global indicator menu forces me to do two clicks to start the application. Ideas? Suggestions?

Comment: Can you post a pic to help me better understand exactly what you are talking about?

Comment: Sorry I cant, because when the menu is unfolded I cant take a screen shot. Therefore I try to explain myself better. When I click on the battery symbol of the indicator area the menu will unfold. If I choose an item of the menu one click will do. If I open the menu and click again on the battery symbol I need to click two times to unfold the menu. Hopefully more precise.

Comment: @dago Sometimes I have those screenshot issues. To work around it, open the Screenshot tool and set the "Grab after a delay of _ seconds" setting to an appropriate length of time for you to recreate the issue after clicking "Take Screenshot".

Comment: You need to clarify your question. See here for unity terminology: http://askubuntu.com/a/19166/8570

Comment: Hello, this question has no information and activity for a very long time. I am voting to close it for now. If by any reason you think this question is still viable or useful in anyways or that there is still a good chance it will be answered please flag it to a moderator or add a comment with the reasons why you want it open. Regards.