# How can I see net traffic in the apps bar?

Tags: networking, indicator, traffic

I have a question. How can I see net traffic in the apps bar? Do I have to install something? I don't want to analyze the traffic, just see if its having incoming/outgoin data transfer.

Thxs!

Comment: By "apps bar", [do you mean the launcher](http://askubuntu.com/questions/10228/whats-the-right-terminology-for-unitys-ui-elements/62842#62842)?

Answer (score 1):

What kind of network manager do you have? I suggest you to install WICD network manager (take a look [here](http://wicd.sourceforge.net/)). Once you installed it, just right click on the tray icon and select 'connection info'.

Comment: I use the default Network Mannager included in Oneric (Newbie in Ubuntu), I'll try this one. Thxs The_Prat.

Comment: You're welcome. Let me know if it works!