# How add panel 3d unity in gnome shell (not panel 2d unity)

Tags: unity, gnome

How to add panel 3d unity in gnome shell, not panel 2d unity.

Comment: By "panel", which [part of Unity](http://askubuntu.com/questions/10228/whats-the-right-terminology-for-unitys-ui-elements) are you referring to? The dash, launcher, what?

Answer (score 4):

I guess this is not possible because unity-3d needs compiz and gnome-shell needs mutter (another window manager) and you can't run compiz and mutter at the same time.

Answer (score -1):

it is not possible.
unity is strongly depended on compiz and compiz is not possible in gnome-shell.
you can use just unity 2d pannel or launcher in gnome shell.
if you use unity 2d panel, you must activate appropriate extension for gnome-shell to put shell panel on bottom and put unity 2d panel on top. but am can't figureout why you want this?
am understand if you want  unity launcher with dash funcion. if you want that find "main meny" app in meny and find unity 2d launcher and check it to be visible in meny. 
then, activate gnome-shell extension "light overview" and you have in activities just window-s preview and workspace swicher.

or use unity 2d panel, cairo-dock , compiz and openbox/gnome if you dont like unity launcher