# How can I put quick launchers in the top-panel?

Tags: 12.04, launcher, gnome-panel

How can I put quick launchers in the top-panel. There is space for many many useful launchers.

Answer (score 2):

You can't put launchers on the top-panel; the top-panel is a part of the Unity Design .

and it it is not gnome-panel anymore, see this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/62842/4937).

You can only install **application indicators:**

see [What Application Indicators are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30334/what-application-indicators-are-available)

Comment: Thank you, that sounds interesting. The problem is that there is no category or systematic way to find them and they don't seem to be supported by ubuntu. So, I understand there is always a risk of breaking when you upgrade the software. What do you think?

Comment: "and it it is not gnome-panel anymore, see this answer." ??  That link is wrong.

Comment: How do you do that, Mathew?

Comment: @Robert the link is fixed, and it is the terminology of Unity. And if you want the classic gnome with the old applets, see : http://askubuntu.com/questions/58172/how-to-revert-to-gnome-classic

Answer (score 0):

Just drag and drop any desired application on the panel. And for removing/moving launcher just hold <kbd>Super</kbd>(Windows Logo)+<kbd>Alt</kbd> and right click on desired laucher to remove or move on the panel.

Comment: this does not work in unity since the panel isn't gnome panel anymore

Answer (score -2):

Simply Drag the application and Place on the panel ....That's it

Comment: No you can't, at least not in 11.04 and newer release.