# Add custom button to launcher which activates Super+W shortcut?

Tags: compiz, shortcut-keys, launcher

Is there any tool that will allow me place an icon on the launcher similar to Workspace Switcher, but activate the "Super + W" command?

12.04 LTS

Comment: I do not understand dashboard. Could you have a look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/10228/whats-the-right-terminology-for-unitys-ui-elements and then edit your question to use the right terminology?

Answer (score 1):

I use [this method](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/05/create-custom-unity-launcher-to-trigger.html) on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

1. Install "Compiz Config Settings Manager."
2. Scale > Bind > Window Picker

I believe this may be the easiest/best way.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to bind <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> to start a certain program that you have in your launcher on the left hand side. I'd suggest that the easiest way is just forgetting about that keyboard shortcut, and instead put focus on the fact that you can always start a program in the launcher by pressing <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>#</kbd> where <kbd>#</kbd> is the number of the app, starting with "1" for the icon right below the Ubuntu button at the top.

If you press and hold <kbd>super</kbd> the numbers as well as a list of keyboard shortcuts should be shown. So in this way, you could place your program as the first one right below the Ubuntu button, and then start it whenever you like by simply pressing <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>