# Skype not present after installing

Tags: skype

I've downloaded skype for ubuntu, but after several attempts at installing it, and ubuntu even telling me it has been installed, it is nowhere to be found.

This either means that ubuntu has hidden it, or that ubuntu has in fact not installed it. I don't know which it is, but would simply like to use skype. What can I do to convince ubuntu to install skype properly?

Comment: How are you installing?

Comment: Have you downloaded the .deb file from official [site](http://www.skype.com/intl/en-us/get-skype/on-your-computer/linux/)  .

Comment: Tell us  what version of Ubuntu do you have (10.10-11.10-12.04, etc.).

Comment: In a Terminal window (`Ctrl`+`Alt`+`T`), what's the output of `which -a skype; echo; apt-cache policy skype\*`? (You should **edit your question** to provide this and other requested information.)

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>Super</kbd> key (called the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key on many keywords), or open [the dash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10228/whats-the-right-terminology-for-unitys-ui-elements). Type Skype, and you should see a Skype icon, which you can click on to run Skype.

When the program launches, right-clock on it in the launcher and set "Lock to launcher."