# Issue while installing Ubuntu 12.04.1.

Tags: installation, unity-dash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)
>   [What's the right terminology for Unity's UI elements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10228/whats-the-right-terminology-for-unitys-ui-elements)

I am trying to install Ubuntu 12.04.1 through a usb stick following the instructions (which ones?) but I am stuck at the second step because I do not know what dash is to search for the Startup Disk Creator.

Could someone explain to me what Dash is and how can I find it?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to AskUbuntu. Dash is the 1st button (by default) of the Unity Sidebar on your left (which has many application launchers). By pressing that button, you get access to a nice interface which is very similar (in purpose) to what the windows start menu is.

As for the program you want to run, you can find it here:
[image]

Comment: DUDE, TRY IT WITHOUT CAPS LOCK, PLEASE! Caps lock = impolite

Comment: He already said it is on the *left* side and he is pointing a it in the screenshot.