# Is there an easy way to locate various programs that seem to be 'hidden'?

Tags: unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are Unity's keyboard and mouse shortcuts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28086/what-are-unitys-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts)

I just updated my wife's 10.04 to 12.04 over the weekend and on occasion I must use her computer. Is there an easy way to locate various programs that seem to be 'hidden'. I WAS able to at one point locate the 'konsole' (terminal program) but found my method of navigation extremely convoluted. Is there a better way to have ready access to less popular programs?

Thank you

Comment: Actually, I am NOT using Kubuntu; it is standard Ubuntu with a few KDE programs added. (I am a programmer who is normally at the command line in Slackware.) When I have to do some things on my wife's machine, I generally go to a terminal. I guess the larger question is trying to customize Unity to mimic the older menu structure of 10.04.

Comment: @apolinsky Have you opened the Dash?  Your applications are there.  The answer to this question will help you navigate http://askubuntu.com/questions/10228/whats-the-right-terminology-for-unitys-ui-elements

Answer (score 1):

If you press the key with the Windows emblem on it the Ubuntu Unity Dash will come up at the top of the screen (it may take a few seconds). If you type a few characters of the program name the program should appear in the list below. Files with similar names, if any will also appear. Click on the program you want to start.

There are "lenses" at the bottom of the dash that can be used to search for particular categories of items. For example there are lenses to find music and videos. Additional lenses can be installed.