# How do I configure the system?

Tags: system-settings

I've just installed Ubuntu 12.04 and am completely stuck on how to administer the system. Initially I just want to open a port on the firewall, but there doesn't seem to be any obvious way to do that.

I've found a "System Settings" panel, but there is almost nothing on it, and the network panel is pretty empty too. I've clicked on various things, but there is almost nothing anywhere. I can't even find an "Applications" menu.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Welcome linucks.  This link might be a good starting point: http://askubuntu.com/questions/10228/whats-the-right-terminology-for-unitys-ui-elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Initially I just want to open a port on the firewall, but there doesn't seem to be any obvious way to do that.

Ubuntu ships with **no** open network ports, but ports are opened by applications so if you have installed or enabled network services (network file sharing, web servers, ssh, remote desktop, etc), then you may have open ports.

Open a terminal session (control alt f2) and after you paste this it will show you open ports:

```
sudo netstat -ntlup
```

[From the UFW wiki page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW).

The easiest way to close ports is to use `ufw`. This will show if `ufw` is active:

```
sudo ufw status
```

(by default it is active).

To allow incoming tcp and udp packet on port 53

```
sudo ufw allow 53
```

To deny tcp and udp packets on port 53

```
sudo ufw deny 53
```

> System Settings

Ubuntu Tweak is a tool someone created that adds lots of settings. [More info here](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/11/ubuntu-tweak-gets-full-ubuntu-1210.html).
You can install it with these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

[image]

But ... I would advice to ask more about specific settings. Mosttimes it is easier just to open a text file and edit that. After you are a command line junkie like some of us you will be a lot quicker setting up a system than with any GUI.

> Network

Rightclick your network connection at the top right. It will have a properties option with all settings for networking.

Comment: Many thanks for the very helpful answer.I'm actually fine working on the command-line, but I'm just puzzled as to why Ubuntu have done this? I didn't need to meddle on the command-line to do this stuff in previous versions so its seems strange that it's become more difficult to do it now.

Comment: Not a problem @linucks :) The more specific the question the better suited for AU. And do not forget to upvote or accept an answer to your question (ofc. the best one you get should be the accepted one ;) )