# Where is the Unity Dash officially defined?

Tags: unity, unity-dash

I've updated the [Unity article on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Unity_%28user_interface%29&diff=530281520&oldid=529186066) and need a better reference from the source on the Dash. However, I can't seem to find any sort of official definition of just what exactly what the dash is, anywhere on canonical.com, ubuntu.com, or Mark's blog. What the heck.

To clarify, I'm looking for a post from a source, be it Canonical or a 3rd party but reliable source, that focuses primarily on the Dash. [This post](http://www.markshuttleworth.com/archives/717) comes close, but it's more of an essay on the progress of the work on Dash, rather than an intro/presentation/definition.

Comment: did you check: http://askubuntu.com/questions/10228/whats-the-right-terminology-for-unitys-ui-elements?

Comment: Yep, see [a previous question of mine](http://askubuntu.com/questions/233938/anatomy-and-terminology-of-unity-dash-hud-launcher-and-panel).

Comment: Whoever downvoted, please explain your rationale.

Comment: I didn't downvote you (for clarity's sake). Did you try sending an email to canonical? Or try and find out on the meta site where this type of info could be found? Thanks for working on the wiki.

Comment: I've [updated the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Unity_%28user_interface%29&diff=530281520&oldid=529186066).

Comment: @DanDascalescu, I don't think that askubuntu posts can be cited as reference, as its not an official Canonical or Ubuntu site.

Answer (score 1):

Found a description for developers at http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/technologies/lenses-and-scopes/, but I was expecting that some sort of "Introducing Unity Dash" page existed somewhere.

Comment: http://blog.canonical.com/2010/05/ found by using Google

Comment: @vasa1: that is at most a mention in passing of the Dash, not a piece/article focused on it. In other words, I can't use it on Wikipedia as a reference.

Comment: Did you go down the article to the part titled "Evolving Unity for Ubuntu Netbook Edition 10.10"?