# Open the dash and search for Startup Disk Creator., Where is the dash

Tags: unity-dash

I'm brand new to Ubuntu looking to install it on a flash drive to co-exist with Windows 7 on a Dell Inspirion computer. I've down loaded Ubuntu and the next step I need to take is to "Open the dash and search for Startup Disk Creator." After several hours of searching I can't locate it.  Can someone assist?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/10228/whats-the-right-terminology-for-unitys-ui-elements

Comment: It seems like you may be following the instructions for creating flash drive from Ubuntu. You need to follow the directions for creating flash drive from Windows. http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/get-ubuntu/download

Answer (score 2):

The Dash is the menu, the icon in the top left of the screen. Or else just press the windows key and that should open it too!