# Installed ubuntu 12.10 and no taskbar

Tags: 12.04, taskbar

So i installed ubuntu 12.10 (from cd) and there is no taskbar all the rest works just the bar is missing.
My specifications are: amd k8 athlon 64/opteron 2 Ghz

Hope someone can help me with this.

Comment: What is the video card of your pc? Type `lspci | grep Graphics` in a terminal and **edit** your question, adding this info.

Comment: What do you mean, "taskbar"? Do you mean launcher? See [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/10228/2355) for terminology.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to **reset Unity**.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:amith/ubuntutools
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unity-reset
```

**Alternate way:**

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
setsid unity
```

Hope this helps.