# Hiding active Windows from Docky

Tags: 12.04, docky

I want to use [Docky](http://wiki.go-docky.com/index.php?title=Welcome_to_the_Docky_wiki) just as an application launcher, I don't want it to show my active windows. I just want application shortcuts on it.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: By Docky, do you mean the "Launcher"? If yes, please refer to this question for further terminologies of Unity's GUI elements: http://askubuntu.com/questions/10228/whats-the-right-terminology-for-unitys-ui-elements

Comment: No I mean Docky. http://wiki.go-docky.com/index.php?title=Welcome_to_the_Docky_wiki