# What is the "Dash"?

Tags: unity, unity-dash

This may be a stupid or trivial question, but I am new to Ubuntu, and have two unsolved problems (flashplayer doesn't play, and scanner doesn't work - in virgin install 13.04), so I started to search in documentation. In the 13.04 specific web site I was browsing the hardware section, and came across something like this: "Open Dash, and select Disk Utilities".

So what is Dash, and where is Disk Utilities?

The application finder could not find any of those. In terminal the "dash" command seems to invoke some sort of a shell.

Comment: In 12.04 it's "disk utility", did you try searching for that in 13.04 as well?

Comment: There is no more *"Disk Utility"* in 13.04. The tool there is named *"Disks"*. What do you need it for?

Answer (score 30):

The dash is what you might call Ubuntu's version of the start menu. You can invoke the dash by clicking on the dash icon on the Unity launcher:

[image]

or by pressing the <kbd>Super</kbd> key (The key with the Windows logo).

This is the dash:

[image]

Searching for "disk utilities" should bring up what you're looking for.

See also: [What's the right terminology for Unity's UI elements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10228/whats-the-right-terminology-for-unitys-ui-elements/)

Comment: Thank you all. I don't know how to create new line, so this is a new line (simple Enter did not work). Why do I need disk utilities? just curiosity. But searching for it in "Application Finder" does not find it. Don't forget, this is 13.04, virgin installation. Apparently, it is not in the menu system, and I don't know what the command is to bring up the GUI application. This is a screen shot of the application finder. Sorry, I cannot paste screenshot. This text-box only let me type characters after characters until I run out of my quota. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Janos You can edit your question with all the extra information you have (including a screenshot). This is indeed that dash.. could you link to the tutorial you're following?

Answer (score 2):

For future reference, the Unity Dashboard was discontinued in 2017. If you're running a version of Ubuntu that still uses the Dash, it's time to upgrade.

> Ubuntu's Unity Dash served as a user interface for Ubuntu to search for files and applications, listen to music, watch videos, view photos, and monitor online social accounts

[Guide to the Ubuntu Unity Dash](https://www.lifewire.com/complete-guide-ubuntu-unity-dash-2202066)