# What is the "dash" and where is it?

Tags: unity-dash

I'm trying to make a bootable usb stick. It says "open the dash and search for startup disk creator". What is the "dash"? and where is it?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [What is the "Dash"?](http://askubuntu.com/q/299295/52726)

Answer (score 2):

The Dash is the menu. The icon in the top left of the screen. Press the Windows Key, it should open it.

[image]