# Applications in folder

Tags: 14.04

How can i open the applications from the folder? Theres an option in mac, where you can access the applications folder and run an app from there.
Is there a way in ubuntu?

Comment: As for an Ubuntu way: The Terminal :) Run Firefox type  `firefox`, run totem type `totem`, you get the point.

Comment: IF you are looking for the launchers that appear in the menu, look at `/usr/share/applications` (and `~/.local/share/applications`). You can click on these directly to open applications

Comment: I don't think this is a dupe? He is asking how to open an application, by clicking on it folder? Right?

Comment: @blade19899 The OP wants to know where the executable files are located, that covers it

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/299295/what-is-the-dash - type in that box it will show you the programs.

Answer (score 3):

Well, yes and no.

Most applications are installed in `/bin`, `/usr/bin`, `/sbin`, and `/usr/sbin` but some may be installed elsewhere like `/opt`,  `/usr/local/bin`, `/opt/bin`, or in your `/home` folder. However, software that is installed may be a library, which are stored in `/lib`.

Thus, really, there is no single folder where all of the applications are installed.

Comment: how can i run, from folder. Compizconfig?

Comment: @acne That would be in `/usr/bin/ccsm`.

Comment: Type `locate` followed by the program name to find all files related to that program, ie `locate ccsm` shows `/usr/share/app-install/desktop/compizconfig-settings-manager:ccsm.desktop` for launcher and `/usr/share/ccsm` or `/usr/bin/ccsm`  for ccsm bin file

Comment: @markkirby Very good point! You may have to run `sudo updatedb` prior to running `locate` though, that makes sure you have the most up-to-date file locations.