# Unity does not show the Application Menu

Tags: unity, 13.04, suspend

Yesterday, I closed the lid of my laptop and it suspended, but today, when open it up, Unity does not show the application menu. However, when I open the new application, the application menu is still appears but not for the programmes left open when the system was suspended.

These are the images to illustrate my situation, I got these from Launchpad, I don't have the external monitor.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/U3Ps7.jpg]

[image]

I have googled this error but I couldn't find any answers. There is one bug report in Launchpad which is quite similar [[here (#998138)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/998138)] but this bug is for external monitor, I use only laptop and this bug has not given any solution. My images are also from this bug report.

My laptop is a fresh installation of Ubuntu 13.04. Would you please show me some ways to fix this problem?

P/S: The terminology "Application menu" is from the post:
[What's the right terminology for Unity's UI elements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10228/whats-the-right-terminology-for-unitys-ui-elements/19166#19166)

Comment: Consider uploading a screenshot of your own problem, please. Have you restarted the PC?

Comment: Hi edwin, Actually the image is the same for my problem. If restart the unity, the  problem could be solved, but later it happens again. Restarting computer is not a good way to solve in Linux environment. Are there any permanent solution?

Answer (score 1):

This situation could be solved by restart unity

1. First step, `Alt` + `F2`
2. Type `unity`

The Unity will be restarted and the problem is solved.