# Unable to find GIMP after installation through Software Center

Tags: gimp

I installed Gimp through the Ubuntu Software Center and the software center says it's installed, but it doesn't appear in the dash and I can't find a way to start it.

I tried connecting to the Gimp website and tried to sign in/create an account & it won't remember my password, thus I can't log in. When I ask for a new password it says its sending me an new one in and email that never arrives. I just don't understand what's going on.

Is there another way to run this program?

Comment: If you hit `ALT-F2`, and type "gimp" in the command line, does it show up in your list of options?

Comment: Is it the [Dash or the Launcher](http://askubuntu.com/questions/10228/whats-the-right-terminology-for-unitys-ui-elements) we are talking about here? Applications with a GUI installed with the software center will appear in the Dash, but not necessarily in the Launcher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open up the terminal(ctrl+alt+t) and then run the below command to run Gimp,

```
gimp
```

Comment: Thank you - it worked - Gimp is now on the list of programs on the vertical panel with the rest of the programs - I didn't even know the terminal exists. I just ran Ubuntus/Linux for the first time 2 days ago so i'm really a beginner. Anyway Thanks again & best regards, Wayne halvorsen

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu,we are so glad to help you.

Comment: When you close GIMP and the terminal, it will probably no longer appear on the vertical launcher panel. If you wish it to appear always, start it again from the terminal and then right-click the icon and select 'Lock to Launcher.'