# How to integrate jFrame Menu Bar into Unity Panel?

Tags: unity, application-development, panel, appmenu

I'm developing a Java application using jFrames, and the application menu bar object doesn't integrate with Unity's Panel ([Window Title & Application Menus](https://askubuntu.com/a/19166/62483)) as any native Unity application does.

Is there a way to do it?

---

My app:

[image: menu bar is on window but not on top bar]

Firefox integration: (what I want to)

[image: use menu bar on top bar]

Comment: This question has been asked on stackoverflow though it has not been resolved.  I think some of the answers may be of use to you though. Its available [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10688847/ubuntu-unity-integrating-with-global-menu-bar) and the answer by Jamel Toms looks promising.

Comment: I've been using the plugin from the page I put above but found it to be outdated.  I will post an answer below with everything I can find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to integrate Java applications with the Unity bar you will need an external library.  There is one called [Java Ayatana](http://code.google.com/p/java-swing-ayatana/) that you can get from a PPA.  Instructions are on that page but I'll put them here

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danjaredg/jayatana
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install jayatana
```

You will need to log out and back in after installing.  The instructions here will install the latest version and will keep up to date, the link I put in my comment above is outdated and must be manually installed so I recommend you use this instead.

From the page I linked above there is a tab labeled "wiki" which has a file "configuration".  This file explains how to set up a Java program to utilize the Unity top bar.  You will need to create a Java desktop application (`.desktop` file).

Comment: I don't understand how to start using it. I installed using those instructions, but now should I add it as a plugin on netbeans? NOTE: I understand Spanish :)

Comment: After enter your three commands (just install it) [it worked](http://i.imgur.com/3AHNAZ0.png) without change anything on my project.