# integrate wine menu bars with ubuntu

Tags: unity, wine, panel, hud, menu-bar

I've seen that it is possible to integrate Java Swing menu bars with the Unity Panel [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/437593/how-to-integrate-jframe-menu-bar-into-unity-top-bar).
Is there anyway to do the same with Windows applications running with Wine?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem like it would be possible to me, the reason being that in Windows the menu bars are in the app window and cannot be integrated into the OS. Since Wine just runs the Windows app in a container, the only way I can see to integrate the menus is to actually port the app to Linux and cut out Wine.