# How do you hide icons in the system tray in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: unity, 14.04, icons

I just moved from windows a few days ago and I find it very uncomfortable to have all the icons in the system tray showing all the time.
How can I hide them into a drop down (kind of like in windows) so I only have a few icons visible all the time, but still have access to all the others just a click away?

Comment: Did you know you could autohide the system tray(its called the launcher in ubuntu)? If not, go to System settings -> Appearance and then click on "On" besides the "Auto-hide the Launcher".

Comment: I didn't mean the launcher. I meant the bar at the top. Title bar? Menu bar? System tray? it acts like all of it.

Comment: So do you want to hide the system indicator icons you mean? Are those that annoying? :/

Comment: I have skype, and dropbox, and lightshot and xdman and i'm sure i'll have more as i spend more time in ubuntu. I just want the important ones there, volume, time, wifi, and net speed indicator. I still want the others just not right there all the time.

Comment: Just fyi, it's called the "panel" :) See [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/10228/whats-the-right-terminology-for-unitys-ui-elements) for more information (note that it will tell you the bar is called the "menu bar". That might be official, most people call it the "panel")

Comment: so there isn't any way? :(

Comment: @Jobin I agree with the Shashwat Black - after installing a fair bit of stuff in Ubuntu, the panel gets pretty full... I'm gonna have to start looking into this myself soon (it already takes-up 1/4 of the menu bar!).

Comment: still no way to do this? :o

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is any way to hide indicator icons across the board - similar to what Microsoft Windows does.

Some applications which also have an associated indicator may have an option to show/hide their specific icon - such as Transmission or Remmina.