# What are the icons on the top bar called?

Tags: unity, gnome, indicator, gtk, menu

[image]

What is that called?

The reason I'm asking is that I'm creating a desktop application in Java (using the gnome java library - with GTK support) and I want my app to be visible there as well with a custom menu.

I can't find anything on how to create such a menu for GTK windows.

Comment: Also look at [**Unity Terminology**](http://askubuntu.com/questions/10228/whats-the-right-terminology-for-unitys-ui-elements/19166#19166)!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's an "Application indicator":

> Application indicators provide a simple and effective API to provide
>   an application icon in the notification area in the top-right part of
>   the screen, and provide simple, accessible, and complete access to key
>   parts of your application. With bindings for C, Python, and Mono, you
>   can integrate your app into the Unity desktop quickly and easily.

Source: https://unity.ubuntu.com/projects/appindicators/