# What is the name of the top bar?

Tags: appearance

I often have to write bug reports where I have to talk about something in connection with the top bar in Ubuntu, but this is rather difficult, because I simply do not know what to call it... So really that is my question, what is the top bar in Ubuntu called?

Comment: It's called Unity Panel or Panel.

Take a look [here][1].


  [1]: https://askubuntu.com/questions/10228/whats-the-right-terminology-for-unitys-ui-elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The top bar of the desktop environment is called the panel.