# Windows 8 host, Virtual Machine with Ubuntu 15.10. Reinstall with more VRAM, is it possible ? Or...?

Tags: virtualbox, windows-8, 15.10, v-ram

I'm brand new to VirtualBox and Ubuntu, both. I have an HP 2000 laptop, 4 GIG of RAM and plenty of VRAM, 1.30 gigahertz AMD E-300 APU with Radeon HD Graphics,128 kilobyte primary memory cache, 1024 kilobyte secondary memory cache, 64-bit ready, Multi-core AMD Vision, but when I run Ubuntu through "V.B." it says my V-RAM is just above 12 and the slider section is greyed out so I can't adjust it.

1. Is it possible to re-install Ubuntu 15.10 again and be able to increase the V-RAM during the process or am I stuck doing it through the Command Prompt
2. When you use the Command prompt, am I supposed to use the Host's Command prompt or is there one to use through the Ubuntu desktop center somewhere ?

PLEASE excuse my ignorance, both VirtualBox AND Ubuntu are new (today!) to me and I'm reading all I can about both to try to get used to each...

Comment: What would reinstalling have to do with it?  Virtualbox only provides a very basic, 2d only virtual video card to the guest.  If you want Ubuntu to make full use of your video card you have to run it for real.

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1:**

Yes you can "reinstall" by deleting the VM by right clicking on it in the VirtualBox Manager window and then creating a new VM in the same way.  Although this is unlikely to solve any problems you are having.

**Question2:**

Ubuntu has a Terminal window, not command prompt.  To open it press `Ctrl + Alt + T`

As for which to use: use command prompt if it's dealing with host side things, use the terminal if it's VM side things (installing software, opening/editing files)

**Side note: VirtualBox will only go up to 128MB for Video Memory, if you're wanting more than that you need to actually install it on a physical machine

Answer (score 0):

You can freely change RAM, video RAM, number of CPUs, virtual network cards, audio devices, and more for any virtual machine. But it requires the machine to be **not running**. Reinstalling the guest is not needed and will not help anyway.

As soon as you had shut down you virtual Ubuntu the Virtual Box Manager will allow for up to 128 MB of VRAM. The virtual graphics card you may have had installed with the [guest additions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-a-virtualbox-vm) will provide many but not all of the hosts graphic card's 3D capabilities. By this it will also make use of the physical VRAM your graphic card has. You may never need more than the 128 MB of VRAM to assign to the virtual guest in addition.

To quickly access the terminal in Ubuntu press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> or search the [Dash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10228/whats-the-right-terminology-for-unitys-ui-elements) for "Terminal". The built in virtual terminals TTY1 to TTY9 can be accessed by pressing <kbd>Host</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>Host</kbd><kbd>F9</kbd>, where <kbd>Host</kbd> is the key you defined to be the "host key" in Virtual Box (e.g. right <kbd>Shift</kbd>-key). Go back to the lock screen with <kbd>Host</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd>.

There also is a command line interface to control a virtual machine from the host terminal, but this is thought for the more advanced users, or in case we had a VM running on a desktop-less server.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to try another route. I figured out how to install UBUNTU 15.10 32 bit (it won't deal with 64 bit) via USB and after install to it's own partition it says DUAL BOOT ? Sure, not what I wanted but i'll take it. Can't get the BIOS to cooperate apparently because I still have no dual boot. I'll keep searching for a fix for this to get a dual boot choice at startup...unless someone can find me a fast-track solution. (HP 2000, Windows 8 Host.)