# Ubuntu "Search your computer" crashes the computer

Tags: unity, unity-tweak-tool

I have just started using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and everything is working just fine except some minor issues, but when I launch the "Search my computer" app, the computer is going nuts, crazy patterns, etc., in the end laptop crashes.

The laptop has 4GB RAM, AMD Turion 64x2 Mobile Tehcnology TL-56x2 processor. Ubuntu type 32-bit.

Similar thread has been posted, which suggested installing Unity Tweak Tool. Even when I downloaded it and minimized the options it got no better.

How could I fix this?

Comment: Are you referring to the [Unity Dash](http://askubuntu.com/q/10228/2079) when you say "'Search my computer' app"? What settings did you try changing in the Unity Tweak Tool?

Comment: Yes i am referring to Unity Dash. My current settings are: imgur.com/wV8tUMI and on the search panel the backround blur is off.