# Move Ubuntu Dock to primary monitor in Ubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa

Tags: multiple-monitors, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

I've just installed Ubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa and I have a dual monitor setup (laptop + external monitor). I want the top bar and the task bar (Ubuntu Dock) on the external monitor.

Problem is that if I select the external monitor as primary, the taskbar moves to the laptop screen. If I select the laptop as the primary, the taskbar shows up on the external monitor, but window switches, notifications and the top bar appear on the laptop, which is really annoying (especially when trying to switch windows).

Why are the top bar and the dock divorced that way?

Comment: @pomsky: [what everybody means by "taskbar"](https://www.google.com/search?q=taskbar). I've been [confused by Ubuntu's peculiar terminology since 2012](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10228/whats-the-right-terminology-for-unitys-ui-elements#comment289879_10245) - sorry.

Comment: Taskbar (cf. Windows) traditionally contains list of open windows, applets, indicators etc. along with app launchers whereas dock (cf. Mac OS) mainly contains application launchers only. Thus Ubuntu Focal doesn't come with a taskbar *by default*. Whenever in doubt provide a screenshot indicating the part in question.