# Tips and Tricks for Unity

Tags: unity

We have the new Unity shell in Ubuntu, what are the fun new stuff we need to know or look forward to?

Answer (score 31):

### Getting Started

- [Homepage](http://unity.ubuntu.com/)
- [Hardware Requirements](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DemystifyingUnityGraphicsHardwareRequirements)
- [What's New](http://www.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/whats-new) (Official)
- [Online Tour](http://www.ubuntu.com/tour/) (Official)
- Rick Spencer’s [Getting Started](http://theravingrick.blogspot.com/2011/04/my-effort-at-writing-help-for-unity.html)(This is a great beginner guide, start here)
- OMG!Ubuntu's [Guide to Unity](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/natty/)
- Rick Spencer’s [Video Guide](http://theravingrick.blogspot.com/2011/04/my-effort-at-writing-help-for-unity.html)
- Jorge’s Video [Guide to the Dash](http://castrojo.blip.tv/file/4998464/)
- Jorge’s Video [Guide to Multitasking](http://castrojo.blip.tv/file/4997614/)

### Frequently Asked Questions

#### Common Questions

- What’s the [right terminology](https://askubuntu.com/q/10228/235) for Unity’s UI elements?
- [How can I configure Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/q/29553/235)
- [Unity Mouse/Keyboard Shortcuts](https://askubuntu.com/q/28086/235)
- Does Unity support [disabling the global application menu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/10481/235)
- How do I [reset my Unity configuration?](https://askubuntu.com/q/17610/235)
- How do I [turn on Unity drag handles?](https://askubuntu.com/q/31877/235)

#### Launcher and Quick Lists

- What are the [custom launchers](https://askubuntu.com/q/35488/235) created for Unity?
- How can I [edit/create new launcher items](https://askubuntu.com/q/13758/235) in Unity
- How do I make a [custom launcher for terminal applications?](https://askubuntu.com/q/34597/235)
- How to add my favorite places as a [quicklist in my home’s icon in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/q/35024/235)
- How can I keep [recent files from appearing](https://askubuntu.com/q/29559/235) in Unity?
- How do I add a [static quicklist that opens a web page](https://askubuntu.com/q/32991/235)?
- How do I put a [web application on the Launcher](https://askubuntu.com/q/31427/235)?
- Launcher icon to [share files with Dropbox - drag and drop](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/04/unity-launcher-icon-to-share-files.html)
- Drag and drop [imageshack uploader](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/04/drag-and-drop-imageshack-uploader-for-ubuntus-unity-launcher/)
- [Show desktop icon for the launcher](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/04/show-desktop-icon-for-ubuntu-unity.html)

#### Indicators and notification area

- How do I [access the system tray?](https://askubuntu.com/q/30742/235)
- [What happened to the weather-app in the panel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29903/what-happened-to-the-weather-app-in-the-panel)
- [List of application indicators](https://askubuntu.com/q/30334/235)

#### Lenses

- What exactly is a [“lens”?](https://askubuntu.com/q/33710/235)
- What Lenses are [available?](https://askubuntu.com/q/38772/5149)
- [5 neat Unity lenses in development](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/04/five-neat-unity-lenses-in-development/)
- [Unity Lens Documentation](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity/Lenses)
- How do I install the [Reddit Unity Lens?](https://askubuntu.com/q/35934/235)
- How do I install the [Ask Ubuntu Unity Lens](https://askubuntu.com/q/31712/235), and how do I use it?
- How do I install the [Books Lens](https://askubuntu.com/q/36212/235), and how do I use it?

#### Task Switcher

- [How to show windows only from the current workspace in switcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62009/how-to-show-windows-only-from-the-current-workspace-in-switcher)
- [Video](http://www.youtube.com/user/whiprush69?feature=mhee#p/a/u/2/XHFNnygpvcM) on how to use the task switcher.

### Developers

#### For application developers

- [Launcher API](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity/LauncherAPI)
- [All API Documentation](http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/)
- [What is nux and what’s it used for?](https://askubuntu.com/q/18413/235)

#### Contributing to Unity

- [Get Involved](http://unity.ubuntu.com/getinvolved/)
- How do I [build Unity from source](https://askubuntu.com/q/28470/235)?
- [Unity Architecture](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=Unity_Architecture.pdf)
- [Bitesize Bugs](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity/Bitesize) (getting started bits of code)
- [Coding Style](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity/CodingStyle)
- Unity’s development [visualized](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2sq4gBpsDLE)
- [I’m a Unity developer ask me anything](http://www.reddit.com/r/IAmA/comments/en0ti/i_am_an_ubuntu_unity_developer_ama/)
- We're the Unity Development team, [as us anything](http://www.reddit.com/r/IAmA/comments/k2nvl/we_are_the_ubuntu_unity_development_team_we_3/).