# Is there some place to adjust preferences for unity other than CCSM?  

Tags: 11.04, unity, settings

Is there some place to adjust preferences for unity other than CCSM?

For instance my mounted volumes don't show up in unity. I am guessing I can turn this on somewhere.

Also I am guessing there is a way to add a custom launcher to Unity that is totally obvious but somehow is escaping me.

Is there an actual manual for Unity?

Comment: Can you split this off into other questions? Some of these are duplicates and the system works best when there's one question per post.

Answer (score 3):

There is no actual manual for Unity yet but [Tips & Tricks for Unity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36274/tips-and-tricks-for-unity) is a good place to start.

Also as Jorge said most of these questions have been asked and answered before here so do a search for Unity and you should get the info you need.

Answer (score 0):

There is simple-ccsm too. The volumes showing on the desktop is nothing to do with compiz. You control that in gconf-editor. This will point you to the item to enable:
http://tombuntu.com/index.php/2007/10/25/hide-partition-icons-from-your-ubuntu-desktop/

Answer (score 0):

You can still use gconf-edit to make some changes. It was the only place I could find to remove text from the icon bars. It appears that Gnome is still in there somewhere. There is also a beta version of Ubuntu Tweak just for Natty you may also be interested in.