# How to show windows only from the current workspace in Unity switcher?

Tags: unity

I would like to make the window switcher (typically invoked with Alt-Tab) in Unity to show only windows from the current workspace. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### For 12.04

This is the default behavior now!

#### For 11.10:

This isn't currently possible, however there is a workaround that you can set that will display the applications in your current workspace *first*, which means you can <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> to it quickly without having to go through applications in your other workspaces. Though this doesn't limit the switcher to the current desktop but it at least puts the apps on that desktop first:

First:

1. Install the [CompizConfig Settings Manager](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/compizconfig-settings-manager)
   (CCSM).
2. Then go to the Switcher tab and select "Bias alt-tab sorting ...." and make sure you check the box.

[image]

- [How can I configure Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29553/how-can-i-configure-unity)

Answer (score 3):

You may not be able to use the current <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> switcher, but there are other ones accessible from compiz.

Try installing CompizConfigSettingsManager (package name: compizconfig-settings-manger). From there you can disable the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> switcher from the Unity plugin.

After that you can enable one of the other window switcher (Application-Switcher, Static Application-Switcher, Shift-Switcher)

I chose to change the keybindings on Static Application Switcher to be <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is a binding for that in scale, (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>) that you can use or change
And or  set an edge for cursor, use  bottom right here