# How to show opened windows in current display with ALT +TAB switcher in Ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04, unity, multiple-monitors, display, workspaces

I am using Ubuntu 16.04, using multiple monitors, when I use <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> to switch between applications, all the windows in all monitors are coming up and it's confusing me. Can anyone know how to show only opened applications in the current `viewport/monitor/display`?

I have researched a lot for this, below are the questions I have seen, none of them worked out.

One more point to note, I am not looking for "showing windows only in the current workspace" that's working fine, but am looking for multiple monitors.

[How to show windows only from the current workspace in Unity switcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62009/how-to-show-windows-only-from-the-current-workspace-in-switcher)

Comment: I'm looking for the same feature as well.
Another alternative I find that may replace this requirement - how to set a different workspace per monitor?

Comment: @AlonL did you find any solution for this "how to set a different workspace per monitor? "