# Where to see the available apps to use?

Tags: 11.10, menu

(Using freshly installed Ubuntu 11.10)
I know this is a totally ignorant question, but I can't seem to find any menu in which to see available applications that I may want to use.
For example, I know I have GIMP installed but where do I go to open it?

Is there anything like the Start or Orb (Vista/Win7) menu?

I know this has to be simple as pie but I can't seem to find it.

Do I open the Ubuntu Software Center on the Windows Sidebar looking thing on the left of the desktop and click "Installed"?

Please tell me this is not the place, it's horribly un-intuative.

Answer (score 4):

Click the grey circular icon at the top =)

See also

http://www.ubuntu.com/tour/

[Tips and Tricks for Unity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36274/tips-and-tricks-for-unity)

Answer (score 0):

The windows "orb" equivalent would be the dash button on the upper left hand corner of your desktop, you can click on it or hit your winkey on the keyboard. Once you have that open, you can start typing GIMP, once you see GIMP, you can click on it. If you don't want to type, you can go to "more apps", then filter for graphics, and it should show up. Enjoy!

Answer (score -2):

Use Ubuntu **Unity's Dash**, located at upper-left side.

or go to file system - `/usr/bin` some programs are located there.

Comment: Not all applications are located in `/usr/bin`.